# PhpStorm 2020 seems working very slowly. Can I impove it?

Tags: phpstorm

After I moved to PhpStorm 2020.1.4  from PhpStorm 2019 it seems to me that
PhpStorm 2020.1.4 works rather slow.
My procesor and memory :

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -i cpu
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210H CPU @ 2.90GHz
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210H CPU @ 2.90GHz

$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8085244     5175784      417904      184048     2491556     2443804
Swap:       2104476       31744     2072732
```

Also in IDE very often I got help hint on items I do not request for help, like : https://prnt.sc/12f6wcp
How to show  help hint only by some action from me(hot key+ click) ?

Also are there some other options to make IDE working not so slowly ?

Thanks!

Comment: **1) Performance issues** -- report to JetBrains Support where they can see your performance report etc as the possible reasons will differ for each user. Use `Main Menu | Help | Contact Support...` for that and provide the requested info there (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems)

Comment: **2) Help appears with no keys pressed:** Disable `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Editing | Show quick documentation on mouse move` -- may be called a bit differently in 2020 version though. Once disabled use usual `View | Quick Documentation` to get such docs popup.